# Angular router: get the full URL of a given route

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-routerlink

Given that my Angular apps runs in `https://www.somewebsite.com/some-path/my-app/`

And I have some routes for example:

`https://www.somewebsite.com/some-path/my-app/my-route-1`

`https://www.somewebsite.com/some-path/my-app/my-route-2`

Inside the application, given a specific route, for example `my-route-1`, is there a method of the angular `Router` or similar that would return the full URL `https://www.somewebsite.com/some-path/my-app/my-route-1` ?

For example in my case such a method:

`this.router.getUrlOfRoute('my-route-1')`

would return `https://www.somewebsite.com/some-path/my-app/my-route-1`.

In other words, what [navigate()](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate) typically does with:

`this.router.navigate(['/my-route-1'])`

in my example would be redirecting the user to `https://www.somewebsite.com/some-path/my-app/my-route-1`.

What if I just want to get the URL as a string instead of triggering the actual navigation?

Comment: You can do this using `ActivatedRoute` or `Location` if you inject one of them in your constructor. Angular provides good documentation on these.

Answer (score 0):

```js
constructor(private router: Router) {
  console.lgo(router.url);
}
```

This will give you the router URL, simply add the `location.origin` before it and you should be good

Also, you can simply use `location.href` to get it full, but I imagine you don't want that

Comment: already tried it but unfortunately `router.url` is not giving only the angular route path, but the actual full path

Comment: [Are you sure about that ?](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zmqksr?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts%3AL23&title=Angular%20Starter)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Router's `createUrlTree` method and then pass result to  `serializeUrl`.